# how to get data in the structure

Tags: ios, swift

my json response is

```
 {
     "success" : "1",
      "totalpage" : "2",
      "blogdata" : [
         {
          "int_glocode" : "18",
          "var_blogtitle" : "ssss",
          "tblogdescription" : "ssssss",
          "var_images" : "http//url",
          "dt_creatdate" : "21-8-2017",
          "flag" : "false"
         }
        {
          "int_glocode" : "19",
          "var_blogtitle" : "ssss",
          "tblogdescription" : "ssssss",
          "var_images" : "http//url",
          "dt_creatdate" : "21-8-2017",
          "flag" : "false"
         }
      ]
    }
```

my code is this. i use alamofire and swiftyjson in this code

```
 struct Data:Decodable {
 var var_image: String
 var tblogdescription : String
 var var_blogtitle: String

 init(blogdata:[String:Any]) {
 self.var_blogtitle = blogdata["var_blogtitle"] as! String
 self.tblogdescription = blogdata["tblogdescription"] as! String
 self.var_image = blogdata["var_image"] as! String

  }
}
```

i take this array to store data

```
 var datadetail = [Data]()
```

then my json part is this

```
Alamofire.request("url", method: .post, parameters: ["API":"get_blog_list","user_id":"18","page":"1"], encoding: URLEncoding.default).responseJSON { (response) in

 guard let datastring = response.result.value else { return }

        if let data = datastring as? [String: Any] {
            if let data1 = data["blogdata"] as? [[String:Any]] {
                for data2 in data1 {
                    if let data3 = data2 as? [String: Any] {
                        let var_blogtitle = data3["var_blogtitle"] as? String
                        let var_image = data3["var_image"] as? String
                        let tblogdescription = data3["tblogdescription"] as? String

                       self.datadetail.append(Data(blogdata: tblogdescription))
                        self.datadetail.append(Data(blogdata: var_image))
                        self.datadetail.append(Data(blogdata: var_blogtitle))
                    }
                    else{
                        print("Error")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i want to data of var_blogtitle ,var_image, tblogdescription in to the structure so that i show that data in to the table view. i try this code and i got the response. i got the var_blogtitle ,var_image, tblogdescription data but i got error in to the append part. i think my struct part is wrong. please help me.
thank you in advance.

Comment: change struct name by default Data property available in ios and init your [String:Any] not variables

Comment: **Never** name structs as `Data`. It could clash with the existing Swift `Data` struct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your struct name

```
struct Values:Decodable {
 var var_image: String
 var tblogdescription : String
 var var_blogtitle: String

 init(blogdata:[String:Any]) {
 self.var_blogtitle = blogdata["var_blogtitle"] as! String
 self.tblogdescription = blogdata["tblogdescription"] as! String
 self.var_image = blogdata["var_image"] as! String

  }
}
```

and

```
Alamofire.request("url", method: .post, parameters: ["API":"get_blog_list","user_id":"18","page":"1"], encoding: URLEncoding.default).responseJSON { (response) in

 guard let datastring = response.result.value else { return }

        if let data = datastring as? [String: Any] {
            if let data1 = data["blogdata"] as? [[String:Any]] {
                for data2 in data1 {
                    if let data3 = data2 as? [String: Any] {

                       self.datadetail.append(Values(blogdata: data3))
                    }
                    else{
                        print("Error")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

tableview part is this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return datadetail.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! detailsTableViewCell

     let value = datadetail[indexPath.row]
    cell.descriptionlabel.text = value.tblogdescription
    cell.titlelabel.text = value.var_blogtitle



    return cell
}
```

Comment: if i take this array  var datadetail = [Values]().   then i print datadetail so i get the append values in datadetail write?

Comment: then i take value in table view like this .   cell.datalabel.text = datadetail[indexPath.row].var_blogtitle . and this title show in tableview. write?

Comment: but when i print datadetail in output i get [ ] no data in it.

Comment: check my edited answer and make sure your array datadetail have values

Comment: i got data in to the print statement but not in to the table data after changes.

Comment: then u must check cell properties

Comment: i edited the above code. data  did not show in tableview.

Comment: Check your IBOutlet connection, frame of your lables

Comment: my cell is custom.

Comment: can you pls print the label frame and share log here

Comment: error like this :  operation failed because the connection was cleanly shut down with a close_notify alert

Comment: can you pls print the label frame and share log here.  i cannot understand this

Comment: cell.descriptionlabel.frame print this and share log

Comment: swiftyjson try[72045:3286933] [BoringSSL] Function boringssl_session_errorlog: line 2871 [boringssl_session_read] this type error

Comment: I am not sure about this error can pls share your code or pls wait let me make a sample

Comment: any email id for share my project?

Comment: karthisiva21 my skype id pls request here

Comment: my url is this :  "https://citechnology.in/GIIS/cipanel/blog/blog_list"

Comment: after reload my tableview i got data into the tableview

Comment: Sir Thank you very much for helping me. Thank You for Giving Me Your Valuable Time

Comment: Have a great day

Answer (score 0):

set always optional if you have not sure in your api have value or not

```
struct Data:Decodable {
 var var_image: String?
 var tblogdescription : String?
 var var_blogtitle: String?

 init(blogdata:[String:Any]) {
 self.var_blogtitle = blogdata["var_blogtitle"] as? String
 self.tblogdescription = blogdata["tblogdescription"] as? String
 self.var_image = blogdata["var_image"] as? String

  }
}
```

*if still you getting error then edit your question and show your error*

Answer (score 0):

Use the struct with following format for your response. Keep the properties optional if you are not sure if they will appear each time.

```
struct Response: Decodable {
    var success: String
    var totalpage: String
    var blogdata: [BlogData]
}

struct BlogData: Decodable {
    var int_glocode: String
    var var_blogtitle: String?
    var tblogdescription: String?
    var var_images: String?
    var dt_creatdate: String?
    var flag: String
}
```

Just parse the response in your `Response` modal as:

```
var responseModal = Response()
if let data = response.result.value as? [String: Any] {
    do {
        let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: data, options: .prettyPrinted)
        responseModal = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: jsonData)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are all members in `BlogData`  optional? The JSON clearly contains all fields in the dictionaries.

Comment: Yes I just kept it to show that we can handle the situation if keys do not appear at all.

Comment: @vadian, updated answer for struct `Response` and some keys of struct `BlogData` as well.